# Creating a prototype function to destroy itself?

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection, prototype

I'm currently working with sockets.io in Node.js, I have a class called Rooms, their functions are self explanatory, its basic model looks like:

```
Room (owner)
this.owner = owner
occupants = []

Room.prototype = {
    sendMessage()
    getUsers()
    leaveParty()
}
```

But I want to make one for destroying its self, I tried doing,

```
Room.prototype.destroy = function() {
    this = undefined        
}
```

and then doing

```
var roomVariable = new Room('blah');
roomVariable.destroy.call(roomVariable);
```

But that does not work, I'm running out of ideas on how to make this destroy its self, basically after there are no more users left in occupants, I want it erased from memory and all. Thanks!

Comment: You can't. You'll need to remove all references to the instance, and allow the garbage collector to clean things up when it gets around to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick answer is: you can't.

Long answer is: destruction of a JS object and subsequent garbage collection is only possible outside of scope. You will need to hunt down and `delete`/unset all references of an item. This sucks, I know, but that's how it is.

Much like in PHP, `this` in a prototype method is actually not the object itself, merely an interface to it. You can't unset it, you can't re-define it (it'd lead to chaos and confusion otherwise).

The proper form for this is to let something else, an object manager, know that you intend to delete this. At which point, this object does the actual GC.

Comment: Cool so if I unset everything that points to that instance of the object, garbage collection will take care of the rest?

Comment: @XCritics: provided that there are exactly 0 references to the object anywhere in any scope, it will get GCed.

Comment: @SébastienRenauld: Zero references only if you don't count circular references (which are allowed)

Answer (score 1):

Your `Room`'s `destroy()`/`dispose()` method should release any resources that must be explicitly released (like an open transaction that doesn't auto-commit) and signal any known "watchers" or "subscribers" that it's closing (so they can remove their references to it). this can include your `RoomContainer`, or you can make your `RoomContainer` responsible for removing references to expired rooms. In either case, once there are no more references to the room, the garbage collector is free to remove it from memory.